# Spring-Maven: Unable to load Javascript file

Tags: java, javascript, css, spring, maven

Following is the folder structure of my application,

[image: Application Folder Structure]

I have created a **resource** folder under **webapp** which has resource folders for **CSS** and **JS**

In the servlet-context file I have mapped the resources to resources/inspiremetheme as below,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/inspiremetheme/" />
```

I have included in JSP page as below,

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/inspireme.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="resources/css/global.css"/>" />
</head>
```

The problem here is I am not able to load my JS files where as the CSS file is loaded properly.
I was not able to understand what I have missed.

Update - 1: 
The file structure after unzipping is as below,

```
Inspireme 
   |
   |------ META-INF
   | 
   |------resources --> inspiremetheme --> css and js folders
   |
   |------ WEB-INF --> classes, jsp, lib, web.xml
```

Comment: Have you checked your .war file? Try unzipping (unjarring) it to see how it was built.

Comment: What about that "inspiremetheme" directory between "resources" and "js"?  Your path doesn't include that.

Comment: @Pointy I gave the path in the Spring context file. 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/inspiremetheme/" />

Comment: Yes, but the `<script>` tag doesn't include it. The browser does not have any idea about your Spring configuration.

Comment: @ElGuapo I have updated the file structure after unzipping. Please have a look.

Comment: @Pointy Agreed. So how to handle this issue? Can you give a shot.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but can you show the rest of your spring config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You messed `<c:url value=".."/>` into script tags..

```
<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" var="myUrl" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="${myUrl}"/><!-- comment --></script>
```

**Also put a comment inside** : this will prevent the jspx parser from minimizing the tag.

If parser minimize your tag you will have as result:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WEBAPP/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>
```

and not

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WEBAPP/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

This can cause some browser not working

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: +1 worked like a charm. May I know the reason also please? What I have missed .. why is it not working before?

Comment: @Che The reason for the comment?

Comment: Naah .. the reason for which it was not working before ..? What if I give the whole path that is assume that I have not mentioned in the context file about the location then how would I give the path?

Comment: @Che Without c:url you will have in your html: <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>. With c:url you will have: <script type="text/javascript" src="/WEBAPP/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>. Check html generated code from your browser in the first and in the second case to see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use *Java config* instead of *xml*, than go for the following solution.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".xml");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/inspiremetheme/css/**", "/inspiremetheme/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/inspiremetheme/css/", "classpath:/inspiremetheme/js/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```